# Increment floating point numbers with the precision of the input with Java

Tags: java, math, floating-point, double, precision

I am looking for the most optimized and easy to read version of incrementing a floating point number with its own precision:

```
increment(1000) should return 1001
increment(100.1) should return 100.2
increment(0.1) should return 0.2
increment(0.01) should return 0.02
increment(0.001) should return 0.002
increment(0.0009) should return 0.0010
increment(0.000123) should return 0.000124
increment(increment(0.0009)) should return 0.002
```

It could be done by string operation but I don't want to convert this to string and parse it back to double.

I have done the following with String operations:

```
public static double incrementWithMover(double value){
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0", DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH));
    df.setMaximumFractionDigits(340); //340 = DecimalFormat.DOUBLE_FRACTION_DIGITS
    String valueString = df.format(value);
    String[] splitted = valueString.split("\\.");

    StringBuilder mover = new StringBuilder();

    if(splitted.length == 2){ // Floating Decimals
        int precision = splitted[1].length();
        df.setMaximumFractionDigits(precision);
        mover = new StringBuilder("0.");
        for(int i =1; i<precision; i++){
            mover.append("0");
        }

        mover.append("1");
    }
    else{   // Non Floating Decimals
        mover = new StringBuilder("1");
    }


    double incremented = Double.parseDouble(valueString) + Double.parseDouble(mover.toString());
    return Double.parseDouble(df.format(incremented));
}
```

I am trying to write this method due to I am checking different values and trying to increment all the values in their own precision by one

What could be the best way to write such `incrementFloating` method?

Comment: if the number is `.000123` what should the next increment be?

Comment: it should be 000124

Comment: You must keep it a string. There is no double value equal to 0.1 or 0.2 or any of the other values in your example. This BigDecimal class may make the whole job easier.

Comment: What should `incrementFloating(incrementFloating(0.0009))` return? If the first increment returns `0.0010`, should the second return `0.002` or `0.0011`?

Comment: It should be `0.002`

Answer (score 2):

This may work for you.  Changed from doubles to strings.

```
String[] vals = { "1000","1000.1", ".1", ".01", ".001", ".00123", ".0004" };
for (String v : vals) {
    System.out.printf("%s -> %s%n", v, incrementFloating(v));
}
```

prints

```
1000 -> 1001
1000.1 -> 1000.2
.1 -> 0.2
.01 -> 0.02
.001 -> 0.002
.00123 -> 0.00124
.0004 -> 0.0005
```

The method declaration

```
public static String incrementFloating(String v) {  
    BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal(v);
    BigDecimal increment =
            BigDecimal.valueOf(1).scaleByPowerOfTen(-b.scale());
    return b.add(increment).stripTrailingZeros().toString();
}
```

Comment: `BigDecimal.valueOf(0.1)` is already not equal to 0.1.

Comment: This is working with my use case and I am going to use this code in my project. However I am not sure this is the best possible option we have for such kind of operation. Is it the most efficient way of doing this kind of job?

Comment: I think strings are the best way to go.  BTW, .0004 doesn't work.  Try it and see. So there is probably a better solution.  It worked using string values.  I'm going to post a correction.

Comment: Regarding efficiency.  If there is only one way to do it, then it's efficient no matter how much time it takes.  But there are probably more efficient ways to do this particular task.

Comment: Working with precise decimal values, as you've described you need to, aren't going to get meaningfully more efficient than this.

Comment: The main reason I do not want to jump into String operations is there could be possible localization problems and the other stuff.. Also string operations are taking way more time than the math operations

Comment: The problem is that nothing is as clean as it appears in manipulating floating point.  The repeating finite decimal expansions inherent with most fractional representations may eventually pose a problem.

Comment: I have implemented the behavior I expected with String operations and added it to my question as well. The fact is I am not happy with my code and I would be glad if I could do this operation more basic and readable instead of String based operations

Comment: Well, my method is certainly readable and seems to be relatively efficient considering its using `strings` and `Double.parseDouble`.  But only you can determine if it is "sufficient."

Answer (score 0):

> Increment floating point numbers with the precision of the input with Java

This just isn't how it works.

Floats and Doubles aren't stored like you evidently think they are.

Imagine the whole number line. from negative infinity to positive infinity.

This line has an infinite number of integer values on it. Between any 2 integer values, and infinite number of values exist there, too.

Computers aren't magic. Floats are 32-bit, doubles are 64-bit. A 32-bit, by basic math, can only differentiate at most 2^32 numbers, that's about 4 billion.

**4 billion is way, way less than 2 orders of infinity**.

So how *does* that work then? Well, there are about 4 billion numbers that are 'blessed'. These numbers are representable by `float`, **and no other numbers are**. 0.3, for example, **is not blessed**. 0.3 is simply not a number in the float numeric system. It doesn't exist.

So, how do I explain that `float x = 0.3;` works, or what happens when you run `float x = 0.1 + 0.2;`?

Well, float and double operations convert, silently, to the nearest blessed number.

The distribution of blessed numbers is based on binary (so in decimal they don't make any particular sense), and aren't equally distributed. Near 1.0 there are way more than near 100.0, for example.

That means errors sneak in *everywhere*. The operation you describe fundamentally doesn't make sense here. You can't do what you want with floats or doubles. Period.

Go with Strings, or go with BigDecimal.

If you're interested, here you go:

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(0.3);
System.out.println(bd);
> 0.299999999999999988897769753748434595763683319091796875
```

I didn't make that up. Write that code and run it. What is that ungodly number?

That's the nearest blessed number to 0.3.

So, in double number systems, applying your algorithm, `increment(0.3)` would try to calculate `0.299999999999999988897769753748434595763683319091796876`, which isn't blessed, and the nearest blessed number to that is simply `0.299999999999999988897769753748434595763683319091796875` again, and the operation would do nothing.

Makes no sense.

Strings or BigDecimal, it is the only way. Efficiency is in that sense out the window, but unless you intent to run this op a few million times a second, you won't notice.